# Jackson deserialize JSON with timestamp field

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, timestamp

I have such string:

```
{
   "debug":"false", 
   "switchTime":"2017-04-12 17:04:42.896026"
}
```

I'm trying to get object in such approach:

```
new ObjectMapper().readValue(string, MyObject.class);
```

And MyObject class:

```
class MyObject {
    private Boolean debug;
    private Timestamp switchTime;
    //...getters, setters, constructors
}
```

I have such exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: 
Can not deserialize value of type java.sql.Timestamp from String
"2017-04-12 17:04:42.896026": not a valid representation (error:
Failed to parse Date value '2017-04-12 17:04:42.896026': 
Can not parse date "2017-04-12 17:04:42.896026Z": while it seems 
to fit format 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'', 
parsing fails (leniency? null))  at [Source:   
{"debug":"false", "switchTime":"2017-04-12 17:04:42.896026"};
```

I don't understand why...If i use in debug mode Timestamp.valueOf() with "2017-04-12 17:04:42.896026" - i have success

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think you need to set the expected date/time format using `@JsonFormat` annotation as shown below.

```
class MyObject {
  private Boolean debug;
  @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
  private Timestamp switchTime;
  //...getters, setters, constructors
}
```

You can also set timezone as `@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS",timezone="PST")`

Comment: I had the same exception, but I am using Spring, and I set these properties: spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
spring.jackson.time-zone=GMT. It turns out it needs the 'T' between the date and time format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss

Comment: @DeveloperDude I am having a similar issue could you check my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71361846/spring-boot-cannot-replace-jackson-with-gson-jackson-still-appears-in-logs

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem when I was using lombok in the POJO class which has `@Builder` and `@Value` annotations

I have also added the annotation `AllArgsConstructor` and then it is working fine with my custom deserializer code

Answer (score -1):

The value that you see in debug mode is "toString()" version of actual value of timestamp, so don't rely on what you inspect in debug mode. 
You can use @JsonFormat annotation that helps you to convert your timestamp with specified format. You need to take care of timezones also while converting!