# Serialized Timestamps converting to seconds

Tags: java, json, jackson, timestamp

I'm trying to serialize a `Timestamp` Object to a JSON. But the object in the JSON is displayed as seconds.

This is a snippet of my POJO:

```
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class TimeAndDateDetail{

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss")
    private Timestamp timeAndDate;

    public Timestame getTimeAndDate() {return timeAndDate; }

    public void setTimeAndDate(Timestamp timeAndDate){
        this.timeAndDate = timeAndDate;
    }
}
```

This is my output:

```
{
    "timeAndDate": 1583038800000
}
```

Why is this happening? And how can I get it to keep its original format?

Comment: What is 'the original format'? A `java.sql.Timestamp` doesn't really have a format unless you mean its `toString()` implementation, which is relative to the JVM default time zone on your machine.

Comment: "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" is the original format before it is serialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate the field with `@JsonFormat` to specify the format, that the timestamp will be serialized. Here is an example:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
```

Comment: Does this work with Timestamp? Or do I have to use Date? As I'm trying this solution, but still getting the same problem.

Comment: @Brodiman in fact I have found this answer, that suggests doing the same as I do for `Timestamp`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43373468/7606764

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong then  :(  I've added your example and still getting the wrong output.

Comment: @Andronics Edits have been made.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using jackson, and this is the default behaviour of it.
best way is to disable the related object mapper feature:

```
objectMapper
    .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
```

Comment: Do I add this line to my main Class or a POJO? Compiler is complaining that it can't resolve this.

Comment: are you using jackson? if yes, you should add this line wherever you create the object mapper

Comment: if you are using spring for example, then check this answer to find how to inject object mapper: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32842962/10668681

Comment: I'm not creating an ObjectMapper. I'm using the Produces annotation and letting the system handle that. Can I still throw this line in there somewhere?

Comment: what is your framework?
can this question be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872931/custom-objectmapper-with-jersey-2-2-and-jackson-2-1