# Spring Boot : Cannot replace Jackson with Gson , jackson still appears in logs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jackson, gson

Gson dependency
`implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0")`

application-dev.properties

```
spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=gson
# Format to use when serializing Date objects.
spring.gson.date-format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

Function to handle incoming post request with data payload

```
  @RequestMapping(path = [ControllerEndPoints.AddCheckingPoint], method = [RequestMethod.POST])
    fun addCheckingPoint(@RequestBody reqData: ChartServerVo): ResponseEntity<Ack> {
        var ok = true
        val data = CheckingPointEntity()
        val cpDto = reqData.checkingPointDto
        val gson = GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create()
        val payload = gson.toJson(reqData)
        mLog("json: \n json $payload")
        //val gDto = reqData.gDto
        data.apply {
            name = cpDto.name
            description = cpDto.description
            cpTypeId = cpDto.cpTypeId
            isCumulative = cpDto.isCumulative
            cpCategoryGroupId = cpDto.cpCategoryGroupId
            isTemplate = cpDto.isTemplate
            isTopTemplate = cpDto.isTopTemplate
        }
        cpr.save(data)
        pcRepo.save(reqData.purusharthChartDto.toEntity())
        pcMappingrepo.save(reqData.purusharthChartCpMappingDto.toEntity())
        return ResponseEntity(Ack(ok), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    }
```

JSON Payload

```
{"checkingPointDto":{"cpCategoryGroupId":1641785600780,"cpTypeId":1,"description":"","isCumulative":false,"isTemplate":false,"isTopTemplate":false,"name":"asdf","dbCreateDts":"2022-03-05 11:54:01","dbCreateSource":"","dbUpdateDts":"2022-03-05 11:54:01","dbUpdateSource":"","id":0},"purusharthChartCpMappingDto":{"cpId":0,"id":0,"purusharthChartId":1647652877927},"purusharthChartDto":{"adminID":0,"description":"","endDate":"2022-12-30 11:54:01","id":1647652877927,"isSelfChart":false,"name":"asdf","startDate":"2022-03-05 11:54:01","userId":8}}
```

Error log

```
POST "/api/v1/cp-add", parameters={}
2022-03-05 16:52:32.118 DEBUG 1360 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to in_.co.innerpeacetech.bkp.controller.CheckingPointController#addCheckingPoint(ChartServerVo)
2022-03-05 16:52:32.358 DEBUG 1360 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.web.method.HandlerMethod             : Could not resolve parameter [0] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<in_.co.innerpeacetech.bkp.dto.Ack> in_.co.innerpeacetech.bkp.controller.CheckingPointController.addCheckingPoint(in_.co.innerpeacetech.bkp.dto.ChartServerVo): JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `in_.co.innerpeacetech.bkp.dto.ChartServerVo`, problem: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.ValueInstantiationException: Cannot construct instance of `in_.co.innerpeacetech.bkp.dto.ChartServerVo`, problem: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
2022-03-05 16:52:32.365  WARN 1360 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `in_.co.innerpeacetech.bkp.dto.ChartServerVo`,
```

My data class variable from the error log

```
   @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    var dbCreateDts: Date = Date(),
```

Why is `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind` still present in the logs and why is the params empty in the logs `POST "/api/v1/cp-add", parameters={}`, I am testing the api from postman and the headers and everything is fine and the json is also properly formatted. I am new to spring, what am I missing.

Comment: Is the `dev` profile active? If it isn’t your configuration in `application-dev.properties` will have no effect. Also, AFAIK, Gson doesn’t have a `@JsonFormat` annotation. Are you using Jackson’s?

Comment: yes the dev properties is active, am sending the date in the folling format `"dbCreateDts":"2022-03-08T21:07:32.000+05"`
but I am getting an error which says `Cannot parse date "2022-03-08T21:07:32.000+05": while it seems to fit format 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX', parsing fails (leniency? null)); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "2022-03-08T21:07:32.000+05": `

Comment: the format is correct but it is not being accepted, what am I missing ?

Comment: I solved this issue by adding the date format for jackson in the dev properties file. I am facing a different issue now, could you please check it out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71398392/spring-java-sql-sqlexception-field-doesnt-have-a-default-value